# starting container process caused: exec: "X": permission denied: unknown

Tags: docker, go

I have this Dockerfile:

```
# BASE IMAGE
FROM golang:1.19-alpine AS base

ENV GO111MODULE="on" GOOS="linux" CGO_ENABLED=0

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    tzdata \
    git \
    && update-ca-certificates


# BUILDER IMAGE
FROM base AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go mod download && go mod verify
RUN go build -o producer


# PRODUCTION IMAGE
FROM alpine:latest as prod

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./static ./static
COPY --from=builder /app/producer .

EXPOSE 8080

# RUN chmod +x ./producer

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/producer"]
```

And when I run it I get this error message:

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/app/producer": permission denied: unknown
```

I see a lot of questions and answers related to this problem, but could not make use of them. So please help me ))
I am guessing it is not a permission-related issue as it says, but rather something to do with the way I copy the binary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add user and do ```CMD chown -R user:group /app``` for that user defined earlier.

Comment: Does your application have a Go `main()` function somewhere in its root directory?  [`go build`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) won't produce a binary if not.

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes does have

Comment: ENV keyword is not used when you're building the binary. Move the ENV on the next stage and use it properly, one ENV var per line. Probably it's failing because CGO_ENABLED is 1 by default but not properly set on your Dockerfile